# Creating an Assignment Operator for a class that has Reference Member Variables

Tags: c++

I've been reading a lot that if you need an assignment operator then do not use reference member variables. I understand that you can not re-assign a reference but could you not get around this by just re-assigning all the data within that reference variable in your assignment operator since you cannot re-assign the reference itself?

Something like this:

```
class MyClass {
   AnotherClass& someObject;
   ... 

public:
   ...
   MyClass& operator= (const MyClass& that) {
      if (&that != this) {
         this.someObject.member1 = that.someObject.member1;
         this.someObject.member2 = that.someObject.member2;
      }
      return *this;
   }
}
```

Is there a problem with this or could problems arise by attempting to do assignment this way?

Comment: Most people would not expect that behavior.  But if it works for your particular circumstances, then I guess that is okay, just make sure you put a comment in the header explaining it.  You could change the references to pointers.

Comment: @IronMensan Wouldn't I still have to go through a similar process even if I changed the references to pointers? I'm not disagreeing with you, I'm just trying to understand it a little clearer, I feel like I might be missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could run into problems. Say you have two `MyClass` instances, A and B, which share the same `AnotherClass` object. If you assign A a different value, then you'll muck up B's member.

What is this variable used for?

- If many MyClasses need to share and modify the same AnotherClass, then use `AnotherClass *`. Then just redirect your pointer upon assignment. You'd have to keep track of how many MyClasses own the AnotherClass though, so either keep track of that in AnotherClass, or use some kind of "smart" pointer.
- If AnotherClass is too large to store many copies of, or there's many, many instances of MyClass, then a `const AnotherClass *` would work better. Again, you'll have to keep track of how many pointers to it exist, so you don't leak memory.
- If it's small, there are few MyClasses, and there's no need to share it between them: use normal objects. The performance impact will probably be negligible.

Comment: The issue that you first mention, that could happen if I used a pointer instead of a reference though right? So maybe I'm not seeing how using a pointer is better than using a reference? Assuming you can count references, like you can pointers.

Comment: With a pointer, you can either change the object pointed to (and thus cause the issue in my first paragraph), or change _which_ object is pointed to (avoiding said issue).